# Can't fix Paypal "invalid_client" authentication error

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to test my Paypal integration from `localhost` using Paypal Sandbox, but whenever I try to get an access token from Paypal, I get back the following error:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_client",
    "error_description": "Client Authentication failed"
}
```

I make the request with curl:

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
-u "clientId:secret" \ 
-d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

Obviously I am using the actual client id and secret in the request, and I am SURE I am using the correct client id and secret for the sandbox environment (I double checked).

Curl's verbose logs look like this:

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
> -H "Accept: application/json" \
> -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
-u "clientId:secret" \ 
> -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
*   Trying 173.0.82.78...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to api.sandbox.paypal.com (173.0.82.78) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Jose; O=PayPal, Inc.; OU=PayPal Production; CN=api.sandbox.paypal.com
*  start date: Jul 27 00:00:00 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Aug  1 12:00:00 2022 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "api.sandbox.paypal.com" matched cert's "api.sandbox.paypal.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Server auth using Basic with user 'clientId' // The original log has the actual clientId here
> POST /v1/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
> Host: api.sandbox.paypal.com
> Authorization: Basic QVRQZGl5TTFqeXpQZkdxMW9FQ2xnZG1uUE13VDRQM01yZEJ1MGRGWVZGLWRNVjk1X09xVjZVam1nNU5xRC0wR2ZPT1I3U1ZianYybWQzQXc6RURQSVdoREpPM0dkdndYNVlRaG45QzRCYzBlUTctaEpWZ041ZlVjUlpkbG1Ta0pMelhzZXE0TmpXeEZMV3kwcGdBNE5zTE5MZ1Qyc0pBVW0=
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: application/json
> Accept-Language: en_US
> Content-Length: 29
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 29 out of 29 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
< Content-Length: 77
< Content-Type: application/json
< Date: Wed, 07 Apr 2021 08:57:50 GMT
< Paypal-Debug-Id: 891f84363e502
< X-Paypal-Token-Service: IAAS
< 
* Connection #0 to host api.sandbox.paypal.com left intact
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client Authentication failed"}
```

The problem seems to be here:

```
ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
```

I have NO idea what it means. Could this have something to do with the fact that I'm testing from localhost? How can I fix this?

Comment: No no, I changed that. The original log includes the actual clientId there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decoding the base64 in the verbose log, the client ID passed is `ATPdiyM1jyzPfGq1oEClgdmnPMwT4P3MrdBu0dFYVF-dMV95_OqV6Ujmg5NqD-0GfOOR7SVbjv2md3Aw`

This does not work when testing at https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client , so it is not a valid ID.

( [Link showing the error](https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=ATPdiyM1jyzPfGq1oEClgdmnPMwT4P3MrdBu0dFYVF-dMV95_OqV6Ujmg5NqD-0GfOOR7SVbjv2md3Aw&currency=USD), "client-id not recognized for either production or sandbox" )

---

To resolve this, obtain a new id by [creating a new REST app](https://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/applications)

Comment: Thank you for your help. How can you tell it is not a valid ID? I've just tried replacing "test" with my client ID here: `<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD"></script>` and when I click on the Paypal button I do get the Paypal dialog box... Doesn't that mean the ID is valid? Will try creating a new app anyway.

Comment: If it worked, you must have replaced it with something other than `ATPdiyM1jyzPfGq1oEClgdmnPMwT4P3MrdBu0dFYVF-dMV95_OqV6Ujmg5NqD-0GfOOR7SVbjv2md3Aw` -- i.e. a valid ID.

Comment: Nope, I tried again just now with `ATPdiyM1jyzPfGq1oEClgdmnPMwT4P3MrdBu0dFYVF-dMV95_OqV6Ujmg5NqD-0GfOOR7SVbjv2md3Aw` and it works for me, I do get the Paypal box... Anyway, I have created a new REST app as you suggested and my integration now works. Thanks again!

Comment: https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=ATPdiyM1jyzPfGq1oEClgdmnPMwT4P3MrdBu0dFYVF-dMV95_OqV6Ujmg5NqD-0GfOOR7SVbjv2md3Aw&currency=USD

, "client-id not recognized for either production or sandbox" ... *shrug*